# How to add placeholder on Bootstrap Form Helper plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap form helper for Country/State dropdown. Here is the link
http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/state/#jquery-plugins
I am specifically using example 5

You can see that on their site they don't have a placeholder in the "State" field. Does anyone know how I can make this happen??

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you are asking... could you explain it on a different way? What is exactly a placeholder for you?

Comment: @Alvaro Placeholder text within an input field to indicate what that field is. Hope that helps clarify!

Comment: In order to test I y must buy the plugin, and I wont. But it looks like that by default it won't show a placeholder because the first option is a blank one. You will need to show us some code or a link to where you are using it in orther to help yu further.

Answer (score 0):

Please append text to empty option

```
ex: $("#country option[value='']").text('Select Country');
```